# Could not load module 'vgui2_s.so'

Tags: debian, steam, bunsenlabs

I am trying to install steam on my BunsenLab laptop (Debian 8/Jessie).

After enabling multi arch and `apt-get steam:i386`, I first encountered a missing library error, which I fixed by also installing `libglib2.0-0:i386`, `libgtk2.0-0:i386` and `pulseaudio:i386`, which were containing the right `.so` files.

However, steam still doesn't work, it start, print the "Downloading update" window at ~40% downloading, and silently crash. Running it in native mode (`STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam`) make a new error appear:

```
Error: Could not load module 'vgui2_s.so'.
```

However, I can't seems to find the package containing this library.

How can I debug the problem? Or find the right package for that library?

*Note*: I had to use the `jessie-backport` kernel to support my Intel HD Graphics chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know which one fixed it, but for another app (GOG version of Hacknet), I had to install the jessie-backports version of thoses packages:

- libegl1-mesa
- libegl1-mesa-drivers
- libgl1-mesa-dri
- libgl1-mesa-glx
- libglapi-mesa
- libgles1-mesa
- libgles2-mesa
- libglu1-mesa
- libopenvg1-mesa
- libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
- libwayland-egl1-mesa
- mesa-utils
- mesa-utils-extra
- libva-drm1

Now Steam start and work. Games have other problems, but steam itself run without problems.